# MEF - Does every Import need an Export to be present?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, mef

I have tried searching for this from other posts, but was not able to find an answer, so creating a new question.

I am building an ETL system.

Now I have a class which has the following Imports:

```
        [Import]
        public IDataExtractor DataExtractor { get; set; }
        [Import]
        public IDataTransformer DataTransformer { get; set; }
        [Import]
        public  IDataValidator DataValidator { get; set; }
        [Import]
        public IDataPublisher DataPublisher { get; set; }
        [Import]
        public  IDataUpdater DataUpdater { get; set; }
```

My program.cs has the following code for composition:

```
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigKeys["Extractor"]))
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigKeys["Extractor"]));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigKeys["Transformer"]))
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigKeys["Transformer"]));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigKeys["Validator"]))
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigKeys["Validator"]));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigKeys["Publisher"]))
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigKeys["Publisher"]));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigKeys["Updater"]))
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigKeys["Updater"]));
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Where **ConfigKeys[]** is my config management system, where I can specify, the path of the dll for each extractor, transformer, Validator, etc.

The full process is: Extraction, Transformation, Validation, Publish, Updating.

Certain times, all that is require are 3 functions to be executed: Extraction, Transformation,Publish.
So if the Config system, does not have a path for the Validator dll, I dont want an instance of the IDataValidator interface. 
But if I specify a blank, I get an error during composition.

**Error**: The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced multiple composition errors, with 4 root causes. The root causes are provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
"The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.\r\n\r\n1) No exports were found that match the constraint: \n\tContractName\tCTP.DCU.Models.Interfaces.IDataTransformer\n\tRequiredTypeIdentity\tCTP.DCU.Models.Interfaces.IDataTransformer\r\n"

My question is: For every IMPORT, I may not have an EXPORT and I want to handle that gracefully. Is there a way to do that in MEF? How can I handle this scenario?
I thought of creating empty dummy stubs for substituting, but really is that what everyone does?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to make an `[Import]` optional, you can use `AllowDefault`:

```
[Import(AllowDefault = true)]
public IDataTransformer DataTransformer { get; set; }
```

If there is no matching `[Export]` then the `DataTransformer` property will be left `null`.